# In Python, how can a function of a script be called from within a module that is imported by that script?

Tags: python, function, module, call

I have a set of scripts that each have their own specialized termination functions. Many of these scripts call a module of general functions. Some of these module functions should direct the script to terminate.

I am aware that the standard approach would be to have the module functions return values that are interpreted by the scripts (in this case, in a way that causes the scripts to terminate), but I would like to know how to call the terminate function of a script from the module.

Comment: Would be more helpful if you illustrate your problem with a little bit of code, for clarity purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your scripts should register their special termination functions using `atexit`.
(See https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/atexit.html)

Then they will be called no matter why it terminates.
Your general module can then just use `sys.exit()`.

Comment: Man, that has been there since 2.6 and I had no idea about it!